# destruct short lazy sequences to vector or map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Say I have a data structure like this:

```
((v v v) (v v v) (v v v) ...)
```

A lazy sequence of lazy sequences. The inner ones always count 3 arbitrary values. This structure is the result of calling `partition` on a vector.

No I need to convert this structure to the following:

```
([[v v] v] [[v v] v] [[v v] v] ...)
```

**First question:**

Which approach would be preferable here:

```
(map #(identity [(take 2 %) (last %)]) myseq)
```

or.

```
(map (fn [[a b c]] [[a b] c]) myseq)
```

or. something else?

**Second question:**

Would it be less efficient to map it to a data structure like this:

```
({:k1 [a b] :k2 c} .. )
```

Which would make sense for my project in a way. In other words: is the creation of and the access to a hashmap slower/faster compared to a vector.

Comment: there is also a nice higher order function `juxt`: `(map (juxt butlast last) myseq)`

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use transducers for this

```
 (into {} 
       (comp (partition-all 3) 
             (map (fn [[a b c]] [[a b] c]))) 
       (range 10))
 => {[0 1] 2, [3 4] 5, [6 7] 8, [9 nil] nil}
```

> In other words: is the creation of and the access to a hashmap slower/faster compared to a vector.

A vector doesn't (easily) allow access by value, only by key. So if you need to do lookups by `[a b]`, then a hashmap is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

I think your second solution is preferable and just fine :)

Personally I'd go with a for expression:

```
  (for [[a b c] (partition-all 3 xs)]
    {:k1 [a b]
     :k2 c])
```

As for the efficiency of small maps vs small vectors; Clojure is good at both! I wouldn't even sweat it. Go with the most semantically meaningful choice. It is highly unlikely that going one way or the other will make any even remotely significant difference to your performance. Of course if you are really pressed, a microbenchmark using criterium will guide you. What will make a massive difference is how the data is used... as Daniel pointed out.